# Mathematica: Idiomatic way to replace values in a list that match a condition?

Tags: list, conditional-statements, wolfram-mathematica

I want to truncate absolute values below an epsilon to 0, e.g.,

```
Truncate[{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, 1.5] -> {-3, -2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3}
```

I guess I could write a function using Scan[] and If[], but is there a more idiomatic "one-liner" way of doing it in Mathematica?

Comment: I wish I could mark both @dreeves and @Ramashalanka's answers as "accepted." @dreeves fits my exact problem better, but @Ramashalanka's gives the general pattern.

Comment: I gave you a fish, Ramashalanka showed you how to fish. :)  (In the meantime I edited my answer to be a bit more general.  Maybe now it's worthy of the Accepted Answer status you graciously bestowed!)

Comment: Larry, did you see my reply?  I realize this is more than a year later, but if you are still doing similar operations, it could save a lot of computation time.

Comment: @Mr Wizard -- very nice. A little hard to parse at first glance, but performance-wise, it's excellent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built in function `Chop` is almost exactly what you're looking for (it does work on lists, as in your example).  One potential surprise is that it doesn't chop (truncate) integers, only floating point numbers.  So for your example to work as you might expect, first convert your list to floating point with the `N` function:

```
Chop[N@{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, 1.5] -> {-3., -2., 0, 0, 0, 2., 3.}
```

As Ramashalanka shows, to do this sort of thing more generally, I recommend:

```
If[Abs[#]<1.5&, 0, #]& /@ {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}
```

Ie, a lambda function mapped over the list.

Answer (score 8):

Lots of options that all work:

```
Map[If[Abs[#] < 1.5, 0, #] &, {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}]
```

or the equivalent:

```
If[Abs[#] < 1.5, 0, #] & /@ {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}
```

or, if you prefer:

```
ReplaceAll[{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, (x_ /; Abs[x] < 1.5) -> 0]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3} /. (x_ /; Abs[x] < 1.5) -> 0
```

or

```
ReplaceAll[{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}, (x_?(Abs[#] < 1.5 &)) -> 0]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3} /. (x_?(Abs[#] < 1.5 &)) -> 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method (`f3`) that is nearly an order of magnitude faster.

It is adapted from code by Fred Simons.

---

```
f1 = If[Abs[#] < 1.5, 0, #] & /@ # &;

f2 = # /. (x_ /; Abs[x] < 1.5) -> 0 &;

f3 = # (1 - Unitize@Clip[#, {-1.5, 1.5}, {0, 0}]) &;

lst = RandomInteger[{-100, 100}, 5000];

SameQ @@ (#@lst & /@ {f1, f2, f3})

First@Timing@Do[#@lst, {500}] & /@ {f1, f2, f3}

(* Out=  True                  *)

(* Out=  {0.406, 2.282, 0.047} *)
```